# php string replace/insert

Tags: php

```
$example="this is an example of [link](http://webpage.com)"
```

this is an example of [link](http://webpage.com)

how to do make this happen using php functions?

many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple regex solution:

```
$example="this is an example of [link](http://webpage.com)";
echo preg_replace("/\[(.+?)\]\((.+?)\)/", "<a href=\"$2\">$1</a>", $example);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) syntax. You can get an implementation for PHP from [here](http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/).